# Linear Layout centeralization

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, centering

I'm having some problems with my LinearLayout centeralization, here goes a piece of my xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_payment_card_numbers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:visibility="gone"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/secondary_text"
        android:text="You have no credit cards"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I got that layout as result:

[image]

But I would like to center my text message vertically.
Any idea?

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout?

Comment: @JyotmanSingh If it was a suggestion, I would like using linear layout, if it was a question, no there is no Relative layouts im my xml.

Comment: add this line of code in your linearlayout android:gravity="'center|center_horizontal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing is to make your TextView match your parent's height. If its set to wrap_content then it won't be able to come at center as there is no vertical height for the TextView.

Just use this TextView code -

```
<TextView
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:gravity="fill_vertical"
android:text="You have no credit cards"
android:textStyle="italic"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I've added `android:gravity="fill_vertical"` and made `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

I have update my comment. This is tested and working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_payment_card_numbers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="You have no credit cards"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
as an attribute of the TextView.

Alternatively you can also change your root layout (currently LinearLayout) to RelativeLayout, and then add the
    centerInParent="true" 
attribute to TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_payment_card_numbers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="You have no credit cards"
        android:textSize="@dimen/secondary_text"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this this would definitely align your text message vertically

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"

    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_payment_card_numbers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:visibility="gone"
            >

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <TextView

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="You have no credit cards"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```